# Ionic v2 build app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to build my Ionic 2 app to get a .apk but I don't know if I can get it the same way as Ionic 1 (my app runs with Chrome Developper Tools actually).

In the documentation : http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/ it says to do `ionic run android` to build.I only have the emulator correctly displayed but my app is not running in it and I don't see any .apk in my app folder.

I tried the Ionic 1 way, `cordova build --release android` as it is sayed here http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html but after few minutes of many .jar downloads I got this error:

```
 FAILED
 Exception in thread "main"

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe''
finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
 option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 23.223 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\PATH\app\platforms\android\gradlew
cdvBuildRelease -b C:\PATH\app\platforms\android\build.gradle 
-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

Can someone help me manage it ?

Thanks by advance !

Comment: Do you get an error when you run `ionic run android`? Did you run -before that- `ionic platform add android`?

Comment: I got no error with `ionic run android` and I run `ionic platform add android` before. Am I suppose to get an .apk with `ionic run android` that replace the old command `cordova build --release android` ?

Answer (score 3):

try to run the following command

`ionic build android --release`

and you get the apk in MyApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk

Answer (score 0):

If no error is shown after runnning `ionic run android`, you should find the `.apk` in this folder:

`MyApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk`